# Installing zsnes on Lubuntu

Tags: package-management, lubuntu

How do I install zsnes on Lubuntu? I've already updated Synaptic and ran `sudo apt-get install zsnes`, it came up with this error:

```
>Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package zsnes is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'zsnes' has no installation candidate
```

Is there a way I can fix this, or another way to install zsnes on Lubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

The development of zsnes was discontinued and therefore removed from package sources. However you should find the package `bsnes`. This is now the recommended package for emulating SNES.

Answer (score 0):

Have tried a lot of thing to get a working snes emulator.
When i was giving it up, i downloaded zsnes for windows and accidentially ran it, and it worked!!
I did install PLAYONLINUX from software center some time before that, basically it runs great with WINE.
Just make a folder on your desktop (or where you like) and put the downloaded zsnes file there and run it :)
If you have problems with gamepad, install JSTEST-GTK and calibrate!!

Hope this help some people..